# Git commit in history but code changes are not

Tags: github

A few PRs were merged via GitHub merge queue at around the exact same time into the main branch. Somehow this has resulted in the commits all being in the history yet the code changes related to the commits are not there. No files showing any changes either. When the local branch is used to create another PR into main it shows no changes. Pulling main into the local simply removes all the changes and makes it a copy of main.

My theory is there has been a bad merge made by GitHub merge queue automation where it has not fully pulled the changes from say already merged PR 1 and PR 2 into yet to be merged PR 3 prior to merging - unsure though. Throwing this out there in case anyone has any light to shed on it?